# Differential equation question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x^3−x^2−6x$ .

Find all equilibria.

Determine the stability of each equilibrium analytically (not from the phase line diagram).

Sketch the phase-line diagram.

I have solved---
$x=-2$ (unstable), $0$ (stable), and $3$ (unstable)

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: I have done all parts of the question except i do not know how to sketch the phase plane diagram for this equation.

Comment: can you add your contribution to the question?

Comment: Equilibrium: x= -2, 0, and 3

Comment: Edit the question. Then what have you done concerning stability?

Comment: x= -2(unstable), 0(stable), and 3(unstable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you showed two parts of the problem solution in the comments and it is important to show your work!

The equilibrium are found by solving:

$$x' = x^3 - x^2 - 6x = 0 \implies x_{1,2,3} = -2, 0, 3$$

To analytically test stability, we evaluate the derivative of $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 6x$ at each equilibrium point and this yields:

- $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 2x - 6$
- $f'(-2) = 10 \gt 0 \implies$ unstable
- $f'(0) = -6 \lt 0  \implies$ stable
- $f'(3) = 15 \gt 0  \implies$ unstable

A phase line is:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

Compare the phase line drawing to a direction field plot and what do you notice?

[image]